# Show announcement on the site

Tags: status-messages

I want to be able to show an announcement on the site that requires a confirmation by the user before it disappears.

Something similar to [Absolute Messages](http://drupal.org/project/absolute_messages) but I don't want to have all status messages shown that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery for the this purpose. Simply use mouseover event on the  announcement DIV. Write a jQuery function to hide this DIV using .hide method of jQuery. like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#announcement_div_id").hover(function() {
$("#announcement_div_id").hide();
});
});
```

Here announcement_div_id is the id of the div which you want to hide.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that [EU Cookie Compliance](http://drupal.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance) works well for one time messages. It is not limited to messages about cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this earlier.
The way I achieved is via Jquery.

I added a special ID to the the messages I want this special way, else the other ID's were left to default.
Now, if there is no special ID, then use .hide() to hide the div,
else let the module do the rest.

Hope that helps.